# dateFromString() returns incorrect date

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert string to Date, but it result incorrect date.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM YYYY"
let dt = dateFormatter.dateFromString("17 Sep 2015")
println("Date : \(dt)")
```

It result

```
Date : Optional(2014-12-20 18:30:00 +0000)
```

Please let me know where I'm making mistake. I tried other format too, but it return nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format for year is incorrect, it should be `yyyy`, not `YYYY`.

"Y": Year (in "Week of Year" based calendars). This year designation is used in ISO year-week calendar as defined by ISO 8601, but can be used in non-Gregorian based calendar systems where week date processing is desired. **May not always be the same value as calendar year**.

See: [Date Field SymbolTable.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)
Also: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Your date format string is wrong. Change it to the following:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
```

For more information read [Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Before I tried to convert date to string with same format(dd MMM YYYY) and it worked. Why this didn't work?

Comment: From the documentation: "A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the calendar year."